# Use of Spring Boot in Android App using Firebase

Tags: java, android, spring, firebase, spring-boot

I'm new to both Firebase and Springboot. I've been developing an Android Application and for the backend I've been told to learn to create some basic APIs in Spring Boot.

We are using Firebase for database. I'm just not able to wrap my head around why I need Spring Boot at all if It is possible to query Firebase using Java Code directly. If there are some other uses of Spring Boot, what they might be? Is connecting using Spring Boot makes it more secure?

Answer (score 2):

I had a use case a while ago that required to create our own API with SpringBoot and Firebase, it was weird because, as you said, you don't need to create another API above an existing one that is there for you to query it more easily.

Now, what we end up doing is to use Cloud Functions and we created the rest API with SpringBoot and then loaded up with cloud functions and HTTP triggers, those triggers were fetching the data inside Firebase database, it was a really weird thing that I did not agree with that idea, but, we needed to do it that way, but the use case was to paginate results, I still don't know why this was a requirement back then if we could just use Firebase

But, if I would say, I would stay with Firebase over creating my own API from scratch (which is not very easy at first and needs lots of security management)